# WHERE clause with JOIN SQL

Tags: sql, join, group-by, where-clause, having

```
SELECT  AVG(score) AS avg_score, st.name
FROM firstTable AS ft
LEFT JOIN secondTable AS st
ON ft.dog_id = st.dog_id
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(ft.dog_id) FROM firstTable) > 1
GROUP BY dog_id
```

The where clause doesnt seem to do anything. Why is that? - I'm essentially trying to output the average score only to the dogs that appear more than once in the first table

[image]

Comment: You probably want a `HAVING` clause instead.

Comment: You typically GROUP BY the same columns as you SELECT, except those who are arguments to set functions.

Comment: Deleted my answer. Your query makes no sense. You are aggregating your records to each distinct `dog_id` however you have `st.name` in your SELECT clause. Either this is erroring when you run it, or you are running pre-5.7 mysql (or have made the poor decision to turn off `ALWAYS_FULL_GROUP_BY` in a post-5.7 version of mysql.

Comment: At any rate, please share sample data and desired results since it's not clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/egBdAzp I am trying to output the name of the dog and its average score but I only want the average score from the dogs that have more than 1 score in the first table. I hope that makes sense 
From the image, it should display only display 1 dog which is Bobbie.

@JNevill

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use an `INNER` join since you want only dogs that match in both tables and add the condition in the `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT AVG(ft.score) AS avg_score, st.name
FROM secondTable AS st INNER JOIN firstTable AS ft
ON ft.dog_id = st.dog_id
GROUP BY st.dog_id
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```